# Adding and Removing Geometric Coordinate Layers with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am not sure why the polygon layers that i am attempting to remove are not getting removed:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e){
        console.log(map.getZoom());
        //This is going to be a function that gets dynamically built.
        var polygons = L.polygon([
                [43.22519, -107.69348],
                [42.99259, -105.48523],
                [42.26105, -107.7594]
            ]).bindPopup("Potential Geo polygon area of companies with violations.");

        if(map.getZoom() >= 5){ map.removeLayer(geojson); }//order matters
        if(map.getZoom() == 5){
            geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);

        }
        if(map.getZoom() == 7){
            if(map.hasLayer(polygons)){
                console.log("TEst");
            }
            map.removeLayer(polygons); 
        }
        if(map.getZoom() == 6){         
            map.addLayer(polygons);
        }
    });
```

So, the choropleth (geojson) layer is easily removed and added using addTo() and removeLayer() functions. But, that is not the case with the polygons variable. Does anyone know why?

The map.hasLayer(polygons) line does not print to the console, indicating that polygons is not a layer. If that is the case then what does the L in L.polygon() suppose to be?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because a polygon is not a not a Leaflet layer, rather it is [an extension of the Path class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon). It never inherits the `.removeLayer()` method from the [Layer Group class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup). Instead it can be removed like so:

```
window.map.removeLayer(polygon);
```

Refactoring the code snippet to take this into account we get

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e){
        console.log(map.getZoom());
        //This is going to be a function that gets dynamically built.
        var polygons = L.polygon([
                [43.22519, -107.69348],
                [42.99259, -105.48523],
                [42.26105, -107.7594]
            ]).bindPopup("Potential Geo polygon area of companies with violations.");

        if(map.getZoom() >= 5){ map.removeLayer(geojson); }//order matters
        if(map.getZoom() == 5){
            geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);

        }
        if(map.getZoom() == 7){
            if(map.hasLayer(polygons)){
                console.log("TEst");
            }
            window.map.removeLayer(polygon);
        }
        if(map.getZoom() == 6){         
            polygons.addTo(map)
        }
    });
```

An alternative approach would be to use [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0) to create some geoJSON with your polygon latitude, longitude arrays and then add them to the map with the `L.geoJson` method if you prefer the `removeLayer()` method.

Additionally, you can catch and debug many of these errors via your browsers JavaScript console. Here's an excellent course via [Code School](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/) to help you better use Chrome's console to understand JavaScript errors.

Comment: Strange. According to this: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon, which you referenced, you are suppose to use addLayer to add the polygon object to the map. I would think based on the documentation that you should then subsequently be able to use removeLayer to remove the object from the map. I tried your modified approach and it did not work. Thank you for your effort and help in any case.

Comment: Can you please post your console error messages you receive to help resolve this issue?

Comment: I do not get any console errors. I would have gladly posted them otherwise. I tried in both FF and Chrome. Also, what is the difference between window.map.removeLayer(polygon); and map.removeLayer(polygon);? By adding window, you are simply stepping into the window object from the map object and there is no need to do so. Or am i missing somthing?

Comment: I am looking into the geoJson approach which may offer promise. Unless you can give me an example of how you would add the coordinates above into a geometric layer to speed things up ;). Thanks for your help by the way geraldarthur.

Comment: You can convert the L.polygon to geoJSON with the [`toGeoJson` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon-togeojson), then convert the geoJSON to an [L.geoJson object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) to access the geoJson layer methods.